# Swift pod no module found - Nimble, Quick

Tags: swift, cocoapods, quick-nimble

While installing swift pod - Nimble, Quick, - I have faced weird problem. I saw success message for all the pod after pod install but all the frameworks showed me as red. And when tried to import these modules started showing me error as "No such module".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build Nimble and Quick separately just go to the manage schemes and check Nimble and Quick in the show column. After that just build both Nimble and Quick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I am not getting error. Also, framework which was showing in red colour is gone. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

After trying lot of options - even suggested by @Vital - I have seen this problem comes very often. I created a new project and above answered didn't worked.

If you go to the link [CocoaPods TroubleShooting page](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html) and refer #4. Solution seems to work always as it builds pods before building the project target. This is very useful in case you see pod frameworks are red in color and it's not able to find in derived data.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the project with the `.xcworkspace` file not with `.xcodeproj.`

Comment: I did try opening with .xcworkspace as it also shows me entire pod. But still i could not able to do so

Comment: Build is successful but importing the module always through me error "No such module"